# Core Data returns nil for relationship with valid object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a weird error. I have a relationship between a call object and status object. the relationship name from the call object is statusForCall.

the data is imported into core data programmatically from JSON. it will not create a call without a status. the user has no way of changing the statusForCall to nil.

however after a period of time (seems to be days) when accessing calls via a fetch request into an array, when I access aCall.StatusForcall.statusID it starts returning nil. There is no way the code can have updated the statusForCall to nil.

Any ideas what might be causing this and where to start looking?

the cachename is nil throughout the application.

interestingly, if the user redownload the application the problem is solved. The code doesn't change and the data doesn't change (there is no migration - it's the same version) - but for some reason this ALWAYS fixes the issue.

i'm really struggling to know what to look at to get to the bottom of this.

code for setting the status below (edited down for conciseness). As i say the job initially has a status but seems to lose the relationship after a period od of time (i can't tell how long this is as the user is unreliable on this)

```
Call *theCall;

        //see if we have the call on the device - if not create a new one, if we do update that one
        BOOL contentIsInCoreData = NO;
        for (Call *thisCall in existingCalls)
        {
            if ([thisCall.callID isEqualToNumber:[checkDic objectForKey:@"callID"]])
            {
                theCall=thisCall;
                contentIsInCoreData = YES;
            }

        }



        NSError * error = nil;


        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];

        if (contentIsInCoreData==NO)
        {
            [self.postDelegate updateGetJobsAndTimesProgress:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Adding new job: %@",[checkDic objectForKey:@"woRef"]]];

            //new call add bits that will not change
            theCall = (Call*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Call" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

}

```
           //set various properties from the JSON dictrionary – these have been cut down for the example code
            theCall.woRef=[checkDic objectForKey:@"woRef"];
            theCall.shortAddress=[checkDic objectForKey:@"shortAddress"];
            theCall.address=[[checkDic objectForKey:@"address"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];
            theCall.postCode=[checkDic objectForKey:@"postCode"];
            theCall.callID=[checkDic objectForKey:@"callID"];



     //****THIS IS WHERE THE STATUS IS SET – PLEASE NOTE THE STATUS WILL EXIST IN CD ALREADY and the JSON WILL have a valid statusID
            NSFetchRequest *request2=[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"CallStatus"];
            request2.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"callStatusID ==%@",[checkDic objectForKey:@"callStatusID"]];
            error = nil;
            NSArray * existingStatus = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request2 error:&error];

            CallStatus *selectedStatus;
            selectedStatus=[existingStatus firstObject];


                theCall.statusForCall = selectedStatus;

        error = nil;
        if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            //NSLog(@"saved job");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog (@"***BROKEN GET JSON!!!\r\r%@",error);
        }
```

Comment: I stupid question: do you save the context ?. Better thing, you can have a look if it is save in disk.

Comment: Hi, yes, I have a context. i'm accessing it via aCall.statusForCall.statusID

the lines before this where I am getting aCall.callID, and other call attributes allwork fine. the status object should be faulting as i'm accessing a property of it not just the object. The data is explicitly saved using [context save&error];

Comment: and this only happens after a while (looks like days after initially loading the app). and best of all is that I cannot replicate it in the development environment!

Comment: Show us how you are setting the relationship. Looks like the problem might be there.

Comment: hi mundi - i just get a valid status object and set it for the call.statusForCall - i'll add to the OP

Answer (score 0):

turns out that a relationship property had been accidently changed - it was cascading a delete from the many end - which resulted in the one end being deleted.